# lua command lua -e "print("hello") output is nil

Tags: lua, sh

```
lua -e "print(1)"  --output: 1
lua -e "print("hello")" --output: nil
```

When i write 'lua -e "print("hello"))"' in linux shell,but is output was:nil,
'lua -e "print(1)"' output was:1,this make me confused.
How can I print "hello" on the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lua -e "print("hello")"` written in shell is the same as `lua -e 'print(hello)'` due to parsing quotes by the shell.   Shell interprets your argument as concatenation of 3 strings: `"print("`, `hello` and `")"`.
So, Lua prints global variable `hello` which is `nil`.
Try `lua -e 'print("hello")'` to protect quotes from shell parsing.